# Gson error when parsing empty arrays

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm parsing JSON using GSON, but get an error when I try to parse JSON containing an empty array.

This is the JSON:

```
{"Selected":[{"RelatedProducts":[],"ProductReview":null,"ProductId":94}]}
```

and the error produced:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: Expecting object found: []
```

Editing the JSON (a local copy) so that the RelatedProducts array is `null` instead of `[]` prevents the error, but I can't change the JSON being sent from the server.

Is there any way to get GSON to ignore empty arrays (or treat them as null)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your class that Gson uses to put parsed data into contains an array of objects called RelatedProducts?
Is RelatedProducts an array of objects or just a single object, so to speak?